# jquery Error in IE8: 'Object' doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I did something similar to: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/04/thumbnail-proximity-effect/
and just like the original it works in FF, Safarei ... BUT I get Errors in IE 8/7 (not sure about 9).

As I am really new to JD and jQuery in particular I have no clue why this is happening.
Can anyone help?

The debugger tracks it down to this chunk:

```
_getScaleVal= function() {              
                        var st = window.getComputedStyle($jelems.get(0), null),
                            tr = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") || 
                                st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") || 
                                st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") || 
                                st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") || 
                                st.getPropertyValue("transform") || 
                                "fail...";

                        if( tr !== 'none' ) {    

                            var values = tr.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(','),
                                a = values[0],
                                b = values[1],
                                c = values[2],
                                d = values[3];

                            return Math.sqrt( a * a + b * b );

                             }

                    },
```

The debugger complains about these issues:

Line 2 Char 8: Object doesn't support this property or method

Line 3 Char 9: 'undefined' is null or not an object

Line 18 Char 9: 'undefined' is null or not an object

Line 19 Char 10: '0' is null or not an object

Line 20 Char 10: '1' is null or not an object

Line 21 Char 10: '2' is null or not an object

Line 22 Char 10: '3' is null or not an object

You input is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) isn't available on IE before the version 9.

There are fix on internet, like [this one](http://snipplr.com/view/13523/) (not tested by me).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this. The OP should totally accept this as the answer.